# How to add a property for a specific API level on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

my app supports all android versions from API Level 19. So, in one of the app's activity, called About Activity, I have code for two API Levels : post API-21 and before that (as seen in screenshot links below).

This is the code of activity_about.xml for API level 21+. As you can see in this image, the name shown on the action bar is "Simple Weather" (name of the app). And also there is no back button here, which I need a lot.

[image: About Activity for API Level 21+]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_about"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.a5corp.weather.AboutActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/appIcon"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffbb33"
    android:textSize="96sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/source_code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:id="@+id/sourceAt"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/dev_info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/madeBy"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/verText" />
```

This is the code of activity_about.xml for API Level below 21 (that means only level 19). As you can see in this image, there is a back button, and the name on the action bar is "About"

[image: About Activity For API Level 19]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_about"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.a5corp.weather.AboutActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/appIcon"
    android:textSize="96sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffbb33" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/source_code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:id="@+id/sourceAt"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/dev_info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/madeBy"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/verText" />
```

I want to have something like this for activity_about.xml for API Level 21+ as well. Can this be possible?

Here's my Android Manifest File.

[image: Manifest File]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.a5corp.weather">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.a5corp.weather.GlobalActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutActivity"
        android:label="About"
        android:parentActivityName="com.a5corp.weather.WeatherActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.a5corp.weather.WeatherActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WeatherActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FirstLaunch"
        android:label="Enter City"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Thank you,
Aaditya

Comment: I am using a GDrive file link as i dont ave the permission to post two links..

Comment: You donot need to have two xml's for one activity. And just post the code, instead of images.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the quick reply. I do need two XMLs to satisfy `android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"` for API Level 21+ (which is not supported for API 19)

Comment: You can create custom styles like those if you want to. If you see what that style contains you will notice that its the textsize which is 22sp(Android standard for large) and the color.

Comment: so you want the back button for API 21+, is that it?

Comment: @nandsito yes thats it...And also the "About" action bar header that can be seen for the API-19 code.

Answer (score 0):

If your `AboutActivity` inherits from `Activity`, try this:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setTitle("my awesome title");
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Or else, if your `AboutActivity` is a subclass of `AppCompatActivity`:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setTitle("my awesome title");
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

If neither works (i.e. `ActionBar` is null), you'll have to configure the styles and features in your layout and Activity so you can obtain an ActionBar.